# Rails 6 with Webpacker & SCSS not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpacker

I am having two separate issues (or maybe they are combined and I'm missing it). The app was picking up the bootstrap styles, but is no longer doing so.

### Issue 1

When I make any updates to `application.js` no matter how small (an extra line break anywhere in the file) it would kill the imported bootstrap files.

Now I can't get the bootstrap styles to show period.

### Issue 2

When I put the following into the head tag in application.html.erb:

```
<!-- before -->
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<!-- after -->
```

It renders no output to the browser:

```
<!-- before -->

<!-- after -->
```

I'm uncertain if this is a Webpacker issue or what is causing this. Please let me know if any other details are required.

I have a full repo here that you can clone / browse with instructions for bringing up the dev environment with Docker.

You can check it out here: [Funtime Github repo](https://github.com/toddperkins/funtime)

Comment: Do you see any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: No errors in the console.

Answer (score 2):

Webpacker is not configured to extract any css.

1. Set `extract_css: true` in `webpacker.yml`. Setting this to true will extract any css you import in js files under `/packs` to separate css files. In your case any css imported in `application.js` will be available in `application.css`. If you had a pack called `test`, the css will be extracted to `test.css`.
2. Move out `application.scss` from `packs` to `/css` (or `stylesheets`, whatever you want)
3. Update `application.js` like this:

```
import "./../css/application";
import Rails from "@rails/ujs";
....
```

4. Make sure you start webpacker dev server with `bin/webpacker-dev-server`.

#### Here's how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

With Shakapacker:

```
app/javascript:
├── packs:
│   # only webpack entry files here
│   └── online_giving.js
│   └── online_giving.scss
└── src:
│   └── my_component.js
└── stylesheets:
│   └── my_styles.css
└── images:
  └── logo.svg
```

And in the app/views/layouts/mylayout.html.haml :

```
= javascript_pack_tag 'online_giving'
= stylesheet_pack_tag 'online_giving'
```

you don't need to import the **online_giving.scss** in the **online_giving.js** file, Shakapacker will find it.